# I used a local honey badger bitcoin atm to buy 250.00 CAD worth of bitcoins, where did it go?

Tags: time

Ok, so it's not my first time buying/using bitcoin. However, this is the first time I've used my own wallet and purchased bitcoin solely for myself. I downloaded the app Bitcoin_wallet and used a HoneyBadger bitcoin atm to purchase 250 CAD of bitcoin. After I inserted the cash and pressed the done button I printed out a receipt which listed the transaction ID, the address of my wallet, the cash rendered (250), the exchange rate plus FEE($20198.9 + 0.00010007), and the bitcoin purchased amount was displayed. I assumed this information was confirmation that my purchase was complete. However, I still have not Recieved the funds in my wallet.... I guess what I'm getting at is "Does anyone know how long it should take for the bitcoin to show up in my wallet?" I realize that it is not an instantaneous process, but I don't know how long I should wait before contacting honey badger? If it makes any difference I am located in Calgary, Alberta, Canada.

Answer (score 3):

It is advised to put your address into a block explorer such as https://blockchair.com/bitcoin (or several block explorers) to see if the network is aware of a transaction sending money to it.

You should also double-check that the address on the receipt is one of your wallet's addresses. (The main address displayed by the wallet may have changed by now, but it should be possible to open up a list of past addresses).

Most (all?) explorers show transactions even if they are unconfirmed. So if there is no such transaction on the explorer, you should take up the issue with the operators of the ATM.

If the transaction appears on explorers unconfirmed, it may mean you will see it in your wallet when it is confirmed.

If the transaction is confirmed but you still can't see it in your wallet, it may be an issue with your local wallet.

Answer (score 2):

> **I don't know how long I should wait before contacting honey badger?**

Their [FAQ](https://www.badgercoin.com/faq) says

> **I have purchased cryptocurrency but it hasn't show up in my wallet. When will I receive it?**
>
> - Under normal conditions, all transactions are sent instantaneously and are not batched
> - Sometimes, due to network congestion, compliance or security concerns, transactions may be delayed
> - Please keep your receipt and contact our support team with your transaction ID if you haven't received your cryptocurrency within 2
>   hours of the purchase
> - We reserve the right to retain all transactions until we can complete our security checks

So contact them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I appreciate it. I have not yet Recieved the bitcoin, but I have contacted honey badger and I'm just waiting for a response back. As for the address I used, your right, it has changed and so far i haven't been able to find any list of past addresses.